Strange folders and files when first bootup of new bought seagate HDD
So I just bought my Seagate HDD. After installed it, I didn't do anything. Here is DIR output:
PS D:\> DIR


    Directory: D:\


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
da----         5/28/2022   3:55 PM                S1173
da----          9/3/2022  12:45 AM                S1474
da----         7/22/2022   6:10 PM                S1297
da----        11/12/2022   6:00 PM                S1610
da----        10/21/2022  10:46 PM                S1563
da----         7/23/2022   3:50 PM                S1307
da----        10/28/2022  10:45 PM                S1573
da----         8/27/2022   3:55 PM                S1440
da----         6/30/2022  11:45 PM                S1248
da----         1/27/2023   9:15 PM                S1709
da----          8/5/2022   6:10 PM                S1367
da----         1/14/2023   4:55 PM                S1697
da----         7/30/2022   3:55 PM                S1353
da----         7/25/2022  12:05 PM                S1325
da----        11/12/2022   4:50 PM                S1609
da----        12/16/2022  11:00 PM                S1671
da----          8/6/2022   1:00 PM                S1371
da----         2/10/2023   9:15 PM                S1731
da----        11/13/2022   7:16 PM                S1613
da----         9/30/2022   4:39 PM                S1533
da----         11/5/2022   4:55 PM                S1588
da----         2/12/2023   7:15 PM                S1747
da----         9/30/2022  10:33 PM                S1538
da----         8/20/2022   1:45 AM                S1403
da----        11/19/2022   4:55 PM                S1615
da----         1/14/2023   6:15 PM                S1698
da----         2/25/2023   4:50 PM                S1749
da----          2/3/2023   9:15 PM                S1723
da----        11/25/2022   7:10 PM                S1626
da----         10/7/2022  10:45 PM                S1546
da----         2/25/2023   6:15 PM                S1750
da----         8/13/2022  12:58 PM                S1396
da----        11/26/2022   4:55 PM                S1628
da----        12/10/2022   5:03 PM                S1663
da----         2/26/2023   7:10 PM                S1751
da----          3/4/2023   4:50 PM                S1753
da----         8/13/2022   3:50 PM                S1398
da----         12/2/2022   9:02 PM                S1646
da----        11/20/2022   7:10 PM                S1617
da----         5/29/2022   6:10 AM                S1176
da----         8/20/2022   3:55 PM                S1406
da----          3/5/2023   7:10 PM                S1755
da----        12/10/2022   9:06 PM                S1667
da----         12/2/2022   2:55 PM                S1643
da----        12/16/2022   7:10 PM                S1670
da----         2/26/2023   8:50 PM                S1752
da----          3/4/2023   6:10 PM                S1754
da----          3/5/2023   8:50 PM                S1756
da----         9/17/2022   3:55 PM                S1504
da----        12/26/2022   7:10 PM                S1679
da----         9/24/2022   3:50 PM                S1520
da----        12/14/2022   6:10 PM                S1668
da----          8/6/2022  10:32 AM                S1370
da----          6/4/2022   3:55 PM                S1191
da----         9/23/2022   6:10 PM                S1518
da----        12/26/2022   8:50 PM                S1680
da----         12/4/2022   7:10 PM                S1653
da----         6/30/2022  11:46 PM                S1249
da----         12/5/2022   2:55 PM                S1656
da----        12/31/2022   4:50 AM                S1681
da----        12/14/2022   9:37 PM                S1669
da----        12/31/2022   7:31 PM                S1686
da----        10/14/2022  10:45 PM                S1553
da----         12/5/2022   6:55 PM                S1658
da----        11/23/2022  10:03 AM                S1621
da----        12/16/2022  11:05 PM                S1672
da----         1/15/2023   7:10 PM                S1699
da----        12/10/2022   5:05 PM                S1664
da----        11/27/2022   7:10 PM                S1630
da----        11/27/2022   7:48 PM                S1631
da----         1/29/2023   8:50 PM                S1714
da----         5/29/2022   4:25 PM                S1180
da----         9/10/2022   3:55 PM                S1494
da----        12/17/2022  12:03 AM                S1673
da----         1/15/2023   8:50 PM                S1700
da----         12/9/2022   7:10 PM                S1660
da----         1/27/2023  10:55 PM                S1710
da----         12/9/2022  11:05 PM                S1661
da----        11/30/2022   2:55 PM                S1639
da----         8/13/2022   1:40 AM                S1391
da----        12/10/2022   2:55 PM                S1662
da----        12/17/2022   4:50 PM                S1674
da----        12/10/2022   6:15 PM                S1665
da----         9/10/2022   1:30 AM                S1492
da----        11/30/2022   6:55 PM                S1641
da----        12/10/2022   6:55 PM                S1666
da----        12/17/2022   6:15 PM                S1675
da----         12/2/2022   6:55 PM                S1645
da----         6/11/2022   3:50 PM                S1206
da----          9/3/2022   3:55 PM                S1481
da----         12/3/2022   4:55 PM                S1649
da----         5/29/2022   5:10 PM                S1182
da----         12/4/2022   2:55 PM                S1651
da----        12/18/2022   7:10 PM                S1676
da----        12/18/2022   8:50 PM                S1677
da----        12/18/2022  10:20 PM                S1678
da----        12/31/2022   5:45 AM                S1682
da----        12/31/2022  11:25 AM                S1683
da----        12/31/2022   5:50 PM                S1684
da----         6/12/2022   4:25 PM                S1210
da----        12/31/2022   6:00 PM                S1685
da----          1/1/2023   8:50 PM                S1690
da----        12/31/2022  11:05 PM                S1687
da----         1/28/2023   4:50 PM                S1711
da----          1/1/2023   1:00 AM                S1688
da----          1/1/2023   7:10 PM                S1689
da----          1/6/2023   9:10 PM                S1691
da----          1/6/2023  10:50 PM                S1692
da----          2/3/2023  10:55 PM                S1724
da----          1/7/2023   4:55 PM                S1693
da----          1/7/2023   6:15 PM                S1694
da----          1/8/2023   7:10 PM                S1695
da----         6/25/2022   3:50 PM                S1233
da----          1/8/2023   8:50 PM                S1696
da----         1/20/2023   9:15 PM                S1703
da----         1/20/2023  10:55 PM                S1704
da----         1/21/2023   4:50 PM                S1705
da----         6/26/2022   6:05 AM                S1235
da----         10/1/2022   3:55 PM                S1540
da----         1/21/2023   6:15 PM                S1706
da----         6/12/2022   5:05 PM                S1212
da----         1/22/2023   7:10 PM                S1707
da----          7/2/2022   3:55 PM                S1250
da----         1/22/2023   8:50 PM                S1708
da----          7/3/2022   4:25 PM                S1252
da----          7/9/2022   3:50 PM                S1271
da----         1/28/2023   6:15 PM                S1712
da----         1/29/2023   7:10 PM                S1713
da----          2/4/2023   4:50 PM                S1725
da----         7/15/2022   8:28 PM                S1273
da----          2/4/2023   6:15 PM                S1726
da----         2/10/2023  10:55 PM                S1732
da----        10/15/2022   3:55 PM                S1555
da----         2/11/2023   4:50 PM                S1733
da----         2/11/2023   6:15 PM                S1734
da----         2/12/2023   8:55 PM                S1748
da----         7/17/2022   4:25 PM                S1290
da----         7/22/2022  10:30 PM                S1303
da----        10/29/2022   3:55 PM                S1575
da----        10/22/2022   3:55 PM                S1565
da----         7/29/2022   6:10 PM                S1345
da----         7/29/2022  10:30 PM                S1348
da----         8/10/2022  12:12 PM                S1381
da----          8/6/2022   3:55 PM                S1376
da----          7/8/2022   7:46 PM                S1266
da----         8/10/2022  12:55 PM                S1382
da----         9/17/2022   1:20 AM                S1500
da----         7/15/2022  10:30 PM                S1282
da----         9/17/2022   6:01 PM                S1507
da----         7/16/2022   3:55 PM                S1285
da----         10/8/2022   3:50 PM                S1548
da----          6/5/2022   6:05 AM                S1193
da----          6/5/2022   5:05 PM                S1196
da----         6/12/2022   6:05 AM                S1208
da----          7/8/2022  10:30 PM                S1269
-a----        11/30/1999   7:55 AM          32768 ROOT_DIR.CP0

Filesystem is FAT32.
There is nothing wrong actually, but I'm just wondering what happened. I'm planning to format it.
Update: I check in registry editor, the default icon is:
C:\Program Files\PowerISO\PWRISOVM.EXE


It might just be corrupt information. FAT32 has its limits... How large is the drive and the partition you see the files on ?

It has 922GB size.

Evidently you received a used HDD.

Please explain more, I supposed to being nerd enough as I've experienced building Linux From Scratch for my own distro.

Currently, I don't format it. I'm just wondering if I can access old data of old owner.

It depends. Have you tried already and what were the results?

@ChanganAuto Sorry I already formatted it to NTFS. AFAIK that looked like not a human user data but just randomly systems.

the closest hit I can find is that it was potentially used in (perhaps as a hobby modification) a SkyHD+ set-top DVR or other similar device.
